# Responsive Page Bootstrap 4 [ cards and Taps ]

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i'm developing a web app that should be responsive for all kinds of device [ mobiles, Tabs ,  and ofcourse Pc's ] so what i'm working on right now is the user profile page i want the page to be responsive so i used grid system to divide the page like This :-
[Computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7c4Yz.png)
The Code :-

```
<html>
<head><title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..\Styles\profile.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..\Styles\nav-navbar.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="card" style="width: 20rem; height:auto;">
                    <br>
                    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
                        <img class="img-thumbnail" src="..\upload\tmp\32546861.jpg" style="width:14rem; height:12rem" alt="Avatar"></img>
                        <br>
                        <h2><a href="profile.php">Admin</a></h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <svg class="octicon octicon-location" viewBox="0 0 12 16" version="1.1" width="12" height="16" aria-hidden="true"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6 0C2.69 0 0 2.5 0 5.5 0 10.02 6 16 6 16s6-5.98 6-10.5C12 2.5 9.31 0 6 0zm0 14.55C4.14 12.52 1 8.44 1 5.5 1 3.02 3.25 1 6 1c1.34 0 2.61.48 3.56 1.36.92.86 1.44 1.97 1.44 3.14 0 2.94-3.14 7.02-5 9.05zM8 5.5c0 1.11-.89 2-2 2-1.11 0-2-.89-2-2 0-1.11.89-2 2-2 1.11 0 2 .89 2 2z"></path></svg>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block" value="متابعة"></input>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="card ml-5" style="width:auto; height:auto;">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill">
                        <li class="nav-item gu">
                            <a class="nav-link active" herf="#"> عن الشركة</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item gu">
                            <a class="nav-link" herf="#">اخر الدرفتات<a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

well, this code is working responsively With **[ Computers ]** the problem is in the small screen device the
page is not showing the way i want it screenshot :- [android Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0gO6.png)

i want the tab panel to be in the center of the screen and the content to be responsive
and the [Name Tag] under the profile pic and the picture in the center of the screen i tried to accomplish what i want but i failed i made each element of the card in a new row and used the class
**justify-content-md-center** and the profile picture also i tried to center it in the middle of the screen ....

CSS File **(profile.css)** :-

```
body{
/*background-image:url("images/2.png");*/
background-color:rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.3) !important;
background-repeat:repeat;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "hana";
    src: url("../fonts/hana.ttf");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "spirt";
    font-style: Bold;
    src: url("../fonts/spirt.ttf");
}
/* nav items */
.gu{
font-family:hana;
}
/* Profile CSS Style Section */       
.card h2{
font-family:hana;
}

.card input[type=submit]{
font-family:hana;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    body {

    }
    .nav {
    margin-left:auto;
    float:left;
    }
    .col-md-9{
    margin-left:auto;
    float: left;
    }
}

/* Profile CSS Section END */
```

Comment: Please edit the question to add the css and the viewport meta tag.

Comment: @RobMoll right away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could just use Bootstraps Responsive classes to handle the sizes for you, below is an edit of the snippet you shared, hope this helps.

```css
<div data-v-c06aa6da="" class="container"><div data-v-c06aa6da="" class="row"><div data-v-c06aa6da="" class="col-12 col-md-3"><div data-v-c06aa6da="" class="card" style="height: auto;"><div data-v-c06aa6da="" class="text-center"><img data-v-c06aa6da="" src="https://api.adorable.io/avatars/285/abott@adorable.png" alt="Avatar" class="img-thumbnail mt-4" style="width: 14rem; height: 12rem;"><h2 class="text-center"><a data-v-c06aa6da="" href="">Admin</a></h2></div><div data-v-c06aa6da="" class="row justify-content-md-center"><div data-v-c06aa6da="" class="col-sm-9"><svg data-v-c06aa6da="" viewBox="0 0 12 16" version="1.1" width="12" height="16" aria-hidden="true" class="octicon octicon-location"><path data-v-c06aa6da="" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6 0C2.69 0 0 2.5 0 5.5 0 10.02 6 16 6 16s6-5.98 6-10.5C12 2.5 9.31 0 6 0zm0 14.55C4.14 12.52 1 8.44 1 5.5 1 3.02 3.25 1 6 1c1.34 0 2.61.48 3.56 1.36.92.86 1.44 1.97 1.44 3.14 0 2.94-3.14 7.02-5 9.05zM8 5.5c0 1.11-.89 2-2 2-1.11 0-2-.89-2-2 0-1.11.89-2 2-2 1.11 0 2 .89 2 2z"></path></svg><input data-v-c06aa6da="" type="submit" value="متابعة" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block"><br data-v-c06aa6da=""></div></div></div></div><div data-v-c06aa6da="" class="col-12 col-md-9"><div data-v-c06aa6da="" class="card ml-1 ml-md-5" style="width: auto; height: auto;"><ul data-v-c06aa6da="" class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill"><li data-v-c06aa6da="" class="nav-item gu"><a data-v-c06aa6da="" herf="#" class="nav-link active"> عن الشركة</a></li><li data-v-c06aa6da="" class="nav-item gu"><a data-v-c06aa6da="" herf="#" class="nav-link">اخر الدرفتات</a></li></ul></div></div></div></div>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div data-v-c06aa6da="" class="container"><div data-v-c06aa6da="" class="row"><div data-v-c06aa6da="" class="col-12 col-md-3"><div data-v-c06aa6da="" class="card" style="height: auto;"><div data-v-c06aa6da="" class="text-center"><img data-v-c06aa6da="" src="https://api.adorable.io/avatars/285/abott@adorable.png" alt="Avatar" class="img-thumbnail mt-4" style="width: 14rem; height: 12rem;"><h2 class="text-center"><a data-v-c06aa6da="" href="">Admin</a></h2></div><div data-v-c06aa6da="" class="row justify-content-md-center"><div data-v-c06aa6da="" class="col-sm-9"><svg data-v-c06aa6da="" viewBox="0 0 12 16" version="1.1" width="12" height="16" aria-hidden="true" class="octicon octicon-location"><path data-v-c06aa6da="" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6 0C2.69 0 0 2.5 0 5.5 0 10.02 6 16 6 16s6-5.98 6-10.5C12 2.5 9.31 0 6 0zm0 14.55C4.14 12.52 1 8.44 1 5.5 1 3.02 3.25 1 6 1c1.34 0 2.61.48 3.56 1.36.92.86 1.44 1.97 1.44 3.14 0 2.94-3.14 7.02-5 9.05zM8 5.5c0 1.11-.89 2-2 2-1.11 0-2-.89-2-2 0-1.11.89-2 2-2 1.11 0 2 .89 2 2z"></path></svg><input data-v-c06aa6da="" type="submit" value="متابعة" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block"><br data-v-c06aa6da=""></div></div></div></div><div data-v-c06aa6da="" class="col-12 col-md-9"><div data-v-c06aa6da="" class="card ml-1 ml-md-5" style="width: auto; height: auto;"><ul data-v-c06aa6da="" class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill"><li data-v-c06aa6da="" class="nav-item gu"><a data-v-c06aa6da="" herf="#" class="nav-link active"> عن الشركة</a></li><li data-v-c06aa6da="" class="nav-item gu"><a data-v-c06aa6da="" herf="#" class="nav-link">اخر الدرفتات</a></li></ul></div></div></div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
enter code here
```

Comment: You may want to put some CSS in the CSS section of your code snippet...